# Viewing Site Stats?

Tags: support

So I was on another SE site and saw the Area 51 data for the site in the side bar... I thought it looked pretty cool and wanted to see what the similar data was for M&TV... but it's no longer in Beta, so it's not on Area 51.

I'm a bit of a stats enthusiast and I'd love to know if there's a link I can visit to see a variety of stats for this (and other graduated) site.

I did see [this](http://stackexchange.com/sites?expand=true#)... but it's a bit disappointing. The Area 51 site lists much more data than these four bits. If you haven't seen them, [here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners)'s an example.

Also, I'm not sure how to tag this, so some help would be good.

Answer (score 5):

The other answers all tackle site-wide statistics, which are probably what you're after, but to offer an alternative...

I don't know how confident you are with databases and T/SQL, but you can get very in depth information from the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/).

At first glance, it appears highly individualised. For example, a query to find the number of upvotes YOU have for each tag:

```
-- How many upvotes do I have for each tag?
-- how long before I get tag badges?

DECLARE @UserId int = ##UserId##

SELECT --TOP 20 
    TagName,
    COUNT(*) AS UpVotes 
FROM Tags
    INNER JOIN PostTags ON PostTags.TagId = Tags.id
    INNER JOIN Posts ON Posts.ParentId = PostTags.PostId
    INNER JOIN Votes ON Votes.PostId = Posts.Id and VoteTypeId = 2
WHERE 
    Posts.OwnerUserId = @UserId
GROUP BY TagName 
ORDER BY UpVotes DESC
```

However, you can actually craft some fantastically detailed queries to reveal things like:

- Comparison of [identify-this](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this) to other questions
- Flags/upvotes by members of the community
- Most upvoted questioners on the site, etc.

Comment: +1.  With just a little bit of SQL knowledge, you can get stats for almost anything on this site.  In fact, you can get your progress towards almost every badge here as well.

Comment: This sounds interesting.  I'd rather it was something easier because I have absolutely no knowledge of T/SQL. Maybe I'll sweet talk my husband into writing some for me. Apparently, he's competent with SQL (he's a programmer).

Comment: @Catija: Have a browse through some of the ready-made queries. There's all sorts that are available!

Answer (score 1):

This [link here](http://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#questions) has some more data than the [sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites?expand=true#) page......
The stats there included number of question asked, number of answers, percentage of questions answered, number of users, visits/day, questions/day, and site age.

Here's the [Area 51 stats page for Movies & TV](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3698/movies-tv) up till graduation.

Comment: This is certainly **more** stats. You'd think a series of sites set up by programmer types would be all about stats all day, all the time. Maybe that's just stereotyping.

Answer (score 1):

The [site proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3698/movies-tv) is still on Area51, but I'm not sure how to reach it by navigation (I just took it out of my Fullfilled Commitments list). However, as you can see it only shows the stats at the point of graduation, they're not updated anymore (which on the other hand means I can safely quote them here):

> At the end of beta, this site had...
>
> **10.9 questions per day**
> Excellent – 10 questions per day on average is a healthy beta, 5 questions or fewer per day needs some work. A healthy site generates lots of good content to make sure users keep coming back.
>
> **93% answered**
> Excellent – 90% answered is a healthy beta, 80% answered needs some work. In the beta it's especially important that when new visitors ask questions they usually get a good answer.
>
> **602 avid users / 11,479 total users**
> Excellent – Every site needs a solid group of core users to assist in moderating the site. We recommend:
>
> 150 users with 200+ rep (currently 602 users with 200+ rep)
> 10 users with 2,000+ rep (currently 74 users with 2,000+ rep)
> 5 users with 3,000+ rep (currently 51 users with 3,000+ rep)
>
> **1.7 answer ratio**
> Okay – 2.5 answers per question is good, only 1 answer per question needs some work. On a healthy site, questions receive multiple answers and the best answer is voted to the top.
>
> **24,789 visits/day**
> Excellent – 1,500 visits per day is good, 500 visits per day needs some work. A great site benefits people outside the community. Eventually, 90% of a site's traffic should come from search engines.

Other than that, you don't get much farther than [the stats you already found](http://stackexchange.com/sites?expand=true#traffic), I think. However, they incorporate many things from the Area51 stats already.